# How to create a user's document in a Firestore collection with the user's uid as Doc ID

Tags: flutter, firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore

Hi I want to save the login data of the user and use the user's name as UID I can now send the data to the Collection User. How can I set the UID? I Programme in Flutter

```
   void _signUp() async {
    String username = _usernameController.text;
    String email = _emailController.text;
    String password = _passwordController.text;

    Map<String, String> userlogin = {
      'name': _usernameController.text,
      'email': _emailController.text,
    };

    User? user = await _auth.signupWithEmailAndPassword(email, password);

    if (user != null) {
      print("User is successfully created");
      Navigator.pushAndRemoveUntil(
        context,
        MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => Home()),
        (route) => false,
      );

      FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('Users').add(userlogin);
    } else {
      print("Some error happend");
    }
  }
```

Thanks for the help

I want to add a user specific UID to my Firestore  Database

Comment: Please edit the question two explain more clearly what you expect the result of this code to be, and how your code is different than that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the initial question title (i.e. "Setting UID of the data sent to Collection") and the following line of code (`FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('Users').add(userlogin);`) I understand that you want to know how to create a user's document in the `Users` collection which uses the user's `uid` as Document ID.

#### 1. Get the uid

The [`signInWithEmailAndPassword()`](https://pub.dev/documentation/firebase_auth/latest/firebase_auth/FirebaseAuth/signInWithEmailAndPassword.html) method returns a [`UserCredential`](https://pub.dev/documentation/firebase_auth/latest/firebase_auth/UserCredential-class.html) (and not a [`User`](https://pub.dev/documentation/firebase_auth/latest/firebase_auth/User-class.html)). So to get the user's `uid` you need to do as follows:

```
UserCredential? userCredential = await _auth.signupWithEmailAndPassword(email, password);

//...
String uid = userCredential.user.uid;
```

#### 2. Create the doc

By using the `add()` method you cannot set the Document ID, as explained in the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/add-data#add_a_document). For that you need to use the [`set()`](https://pub.dev/documentation/cloud_firestore/latest/cloud_firestore/DocumentReference/set.html) method as follows:

```
final userData = {"username": username, ... };
await FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('Users').doc(uid).set(userData);
```

Comment: Hey @Diplo did you have time to look at the proposed solution?

Comment: Yes sorry for the late reply but the problem i had was awnserd with your help. Thank you